# Is there a YouTube library for Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api

I want to build a Python app to automate some YouTube tasks, so I went to grab their files at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/ and to my surprise, it's a Python 2 library.

I was looking around to see if there was an updated version hidden somewhere, but I wasn't able to find one, and I guess I'd rather ask here than waste more time following random links on YouTube.

Is there an official Python 3 library for YouTube?

If not, what are my options for building a Python 3 application which can retrieve YouTube video data?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-api-python-client/ does support Python 3 as does https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/youtube/v3

Answer (score 0):

The one you mentioned is sole official Python client library and I don't think there's official Python3 version of it.
But if you don't need whole wrapper of all YouTube APIs, it's more straight forward to call API directly using standard `http.client` module or 3rd party `requests` module.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is `pytube` for Python3.

Example Download of a video:

```
from pytube import YouTube

# creating YouTube object
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1csFTDXXULY") 

# accessing video stream of YouTube obj.(first one, more available)
stream = yt.streams.first() 

# download into working directory
stream.download()
```